# Was Moshe punished for converting the Erev Rav?

Tags: gentiles, torah-study, moshe-rabbeinu, yetziat-mitzrayim, egypt

Does anything in the Torah mention that Moshe was punished for converting the Erev Rav and taking them out of Egypt?

Comment: You assume apriori, that Moses converted Erev Rav and ask why, instead of asking whether actually Moses did it

Comment: Is this shiur online?

Comment: FWIW Rashi to Shemos 12:38 and 32:7 confirms your premise.

Comment: @Natanav When you say, “Torah”, how broadly are you meaning it? The 5 books of Moshe, Tanach, Shas & Midrash?

Comment: @Yaacov Deane Torah means the entire Jewish body of knowledge i.e. Torah Sheba'al Peh and Torah Shebichtav. In my opinion any time we want to refer to only the Torah Shebichtav we should use the words Shebichtav or Chumash or Miqra.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to come from Rashi's midrashic explanation of [Exodus 32:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.32.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (quoted from Sefaria):

> וַיְדַבֵּ֥ר יְהוָ֖ה אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֑ה לֶךְ־רֵ֕ד כִּ֚י שִׁחֵ֣ת עַמְּךָ֔ אֲשֶׁ֥ר הֶעֱלֵ֖יתָ מֵאֶ֥רֶץ מִצְרָֽיִם׃
>
> The LORD spoke to Moses, “Hurry down, for your people, whom you brought out of the land of Egypt, have acted basely.

According to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Exodus.32.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), God was telling Moses to *go down* from his high position because *his nation* (his converts) had sinned with the golden calf:

> לך רד. מִגְּדֻלָּתְךָ – לֹא נָתַתִּי לְךָ גְּדֻלָּה אֶלָּא בִשְׁבִילָם (ברבות ל"ב), בְּאוֹתָהּ שָׁעָה נִתְנַדָּה מֹשֶׁה מִפִּי בֵית דִּין שֶׁל מַעְלָה (תנחומא):
>
> לך רד GO, GO DOWN from your high position; I have given you distinction only for their sake! (Berakhot 32a). At that moment Moses was excommunicated by a decree of the heavenly court (Midrash Tanchuma, Ki Tisa 22).
>
> שחת עמך. שִׁחֵת הָעָם לֹא נֶאֱמַר, אֶלָּא עַמְּךָ – עֵרֶב רַב שֶׁקִּבַּלְתָּ מֵעַצְמְךָ וְגִיַּרְתָּם וְלֹא נִמְלַכְתָּ בִּי, וְאָמַרְתָּ טוֹב שֶׁיִּדְבְּקוּ גֵרִים בַּשְּׁכִינָה – הֵם שִׁחֲתוּ וְהִשְׁחִיתוּ (שמות רבה):
>
> שחת עמך THY PEOPLE HAVE CORRUPTED THEMSELVES — It does not say the people have corrupted but “thy” people — the mixed multitude whom you received of your own accord and accepted as proselytes without consulting Me. You thought it a good thing that proselytes should be attached to the Shechina — now they have corrupted themselves and have corrupted others (Exodus Rabbah 42:6).

Answer (score 3):

Shemos Rabah 42:6 
לֶךְ רֵד כִּי שִׁחֵת עַמְּךָ, הָעָם אֵין כְּתִיב כָּאן אֶלָא עַמְּךָ, אָמַר משֶׁה רִבּוֹן הָעוֹלָם מִנַּיִן הֵם עַמִּי, אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עַמְּךָ הֵם, שֶׁעַד שֶׁהָיוּ בְּמִצְרַיִם אָמַרְתִּי לְךָ (שמות ז, ד): וְהוֹצֵאתִי אֶת צִבְאֹתַי אֶת עַמִּי, אָמַרְתִּי לְךָ שֶׁלֹא לְעָרֵב בָּהֶם עֵרֶב רָב, אַתָּה שֶׁהָיִיתָ עָנָו וְכָשֵׁר אָמַרְתָּ לִי לְעוֹלָם מְקַבְּלִים הַשָּׁבִים, וַאֲנִי הָיִיתִי יוֹדֵעַ מַה הֵם עֲתִידִין לַעֲשׂוֹת, אָמַרְתִּי לְךָ, לָאו, וְעָשִׂיתִי רְצוֹנְךָ, וְהֵם הֵם שֶׁעָשׂוּ אֶת הָעֵגֶל, שֶׁהָיוּ עוֹבְדִים עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים וְהֵם עָשׂוּ אוֹתוֹ וְגָרְמוּ לְעַמִּי לַחֲטֹא. רְאֵה מַה כְּתִיב אֵלֶּה אֱלֹהֵינוּ אֵין כְּתִיב כָּאן, אֶלָּא (שמות לב, ד): אֵלֶּה אֱלֹהֶיךָ, שֶׁהַגֵּרִים שֶׁעָלוּ עִם משֶׁה הֵם עֲשָׂאוּהוּ וְאָמְרוּ לְיִשְׂרָאֵל אֵלֶה אֱלֹהֶיךָ, לְכָךְ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אָמַר לְמשֶׁה: לֶךְ רֵד כִּי שִׁחֵת עַמְּךָ.

Rabainu Bachaya shemos 32:6
ומפורש אמרו במדרש כי ערב רב שיצאו עמהם ממצרים עשאוהו והכתוב מוכיח שאמר אלה אלהיך ישראל והוא דברי ערב רב שאמרו לישראל אלה אלהיך ישראל שאילו עשאוהו ישראל היה לו לומר אלה אלהינו ישראל אשר העלונו, וזהו קשים גרים לישראל כספחת בבשר החי, ועוד זה אמרו במדרש שאמר לו הקב"ה למשה לך רד כי שחת עמך עמך ולא עמי הם ולא אמרתי לך ביציאת מצרים והוצאת את צבאותי את עמי ואתה קבלת ערב רב ורצית לקבל הגרים עמך הם ולא עמי, ומכל מקום אע"פ שערב רב היו תחלה עקר המעשה הרע מצינו שטעו ישראל אחריו ונענשו הכל.
Midrash Tanchuma (Ki Tissa 19) states explicitly that the mixed multitude (of Egyptian converts) who joined the Jewish people at the Exodus were the ones who made the golden calf. The Midrash proves this from the words אלה אלוהיך ישראל, “these are your gods O Israel.” Had the makers of the golden calf been natural born Jews they would have chanted: “these are our gods O Israel, who have brought us out of Egypt.“ This episode prompted our sages in Yevamot 16 to say that the process of assimilating converts is as much of an affliction for Israel as being struck with a form of skin eczema called ספחת on raw flesh, a dread disease, (compare Leviticus 13,2). On the same subject of accepting converts Shemot Rabbah 42,6 has stated that the reason G’d told Moses: “go on down for your people have become corrupt, was that Moses had accepted these converts at face value without having first obtained G’d’s permission to convert them. G’d reminded Moses that He had specifically said to him (Exodus 7,4) “I shall take out My hosts, My people, the Children of Israel. He had never mentioned taking out people who were not “Children of Israel,” whereas Moses had taken it upon himself to accept the mixed multitude. G’d now made it plain that He did not consider these converts as “My people.” In spite of what the Midrash writes, the fact remains that though these converts originated the disaster, the natural born Jews joined in of their own accord. This is why all of them were punished.