# Do we have an obligation to love the Erev Rav?

Tags: mitzvah, ahavat-yisrael, sefer-vayikra

Does the mitzvah of loving other Jews(Vayikra 19:18) apply to the Erev Rav?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erev Rav and Modern Israeli Leaders](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/erev-rav-and-modern-israeli-leaders)

Comment: @JoshK One of the reasons that I asked the question in the first place was because I read the answer to the question to which you provided a link. However, in the accepted answer, there is no source provided for the claim that the Erev Rav are Jews and must be treated as such.

Comment: The Vilna Gaon says that the entire purpose of galus is to be *mevarer* who the Erev Ra are, so that they can be seperated from *klal yisrael*.

Comment: Can you provide a link where he says that?

Comment: Your Q. is not clear, are you asking about the historical Erev Rav in the wilderness or about contemporary gentiles?

Comment: @Nosson The implication in the parsha is that the Eirev Rav became *Jews* at Har Sinai along with the Bnai Yisrael. As a result the implication would be yes as an answer to your question.

Comment: @AlBerko The pointer to what is said to be the duplicate would imply secular Jews. The term Eirev Rav would seem to mean those who became *Jews* at Har Sinai even though not part of the 12 shevatim. That might seem to imply secular Jews in our day.

Comment: @AlBerko  I am talking about the Erev Rav, i.e. the people Moishe converted without HaShem's permission. What do you mean by "the historical Erev Rav in the wilderness"? Why do you think that the Erev Rav refers to contemporary gentiles?

Comment: I think he means that practically speaking who is the Erev Rav today. They seem to not exist. You're asking if historically there was an obligation to love them?

Comment: "*Moishe converted without HaShem's permission*" - never heard of people Moses converted. So you should probably explain yourself better.

Comment: @AlBerko You had said a similar thing in Feb 19 in a comment to a question I had posted. The source for Moishe converting the Erev Rav without HaShem's permission is the Rashi to Shemos 32:7 and Shemos Rabbah 42:6. Also the question from last time: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99321/was-moshe-punished-for-converting-the-erev-rav

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It applies to all jews. The Shita mikubetzes kesubos 37b brings the Rama that says viahavta lereiacha camocha applies even to a rasha. The proof he brings is that we apply the pasuk to someone whose chayiv misa about to get killed. Rav Elchanan Wasserman also brings this proof.

Even though the gemara in pesachim implies you have a mitzva to hate a rasha. There could be 2 dinim in the mitzva 1. to love him. 2 to treat him well. Maybe you have to hate him but treat him well...

So if you hold eirev rav were reshaim then at least this din of loving your fellow would apply, that you have to treat him like you want to be treated.
Im not saying they were considered reshaim. But if they would be.